# Почему консоль практически сразу закрывается после вывода?

Tags: delphi

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  
  link=^List;
  
  List=record
    
    number:string[7];
    left:link;
    right:link;
  
end;

var
  beg2L,beg2newL,lastlink:link;

procedure addelementlist1;
var
  add:link;
begin
  new(add);
  add^.left:=nil;
  add^.right:=nil;
  writeln('Введите номер телефона,который нужно добавить');
  repeat
    readln(add^.number);
  until (length(add^.number)=3) or (length(add^.number)=7);
  if (beg2L=nil) then
  begin
    beg2L:=add;
  end
  else
  begin
    add^.right:=beg2L;
    beg2L^.left:=add;
    beg2L:=add;
  end;

end;

procedure addelementlist2(const str:string);

var
  add:link;

begin
 
 new(add);
  
  if (beg2newL=nil) then
  
  begin
    
    beg2newL:=add;
    
    add^.number:=str;
  end
  
  else
  
  begin
    
    add^.right:=beg2newL;
   
    beg2newL:=add;
    
    add^.number:=str;
  
  end;

end;

procedure findlastlink(var lastlink1:link);
var
  last:link;
begin
  last:=beg2L;
  while last^.right<>nil do
  begin
    last:=last^.right;
  end;
  lastlink1:=last;
end;

procedure poisk(lastlink1:link);
begin
  while (lastlink1<>nil) do
  begin
    if length(lastlink1^.number)=7 then
    begin
      addelementlist2(lastlink1^.number);
    end;
    lastlink1:=lastlink1^.left;
  end;
end;

procedure vivod(beg2newLProc:link);

begin
  
  while (beg2newLProc<>nil) do
  
  begin
    
    writeln(beg2newLProc^.number);
    
    beg2newLProc:=beg2newLProc^.right;
  
  end;

end;



begin
  
  addelementlist1;
  
  findlastlink(lastlink);
  
  poisk(lastlink);
  
  vivod(beg2newL);

  readln;
end.
```

Смысл задания состоит в составлении двунаправленного списка, в котором могут быть номера из 7 цифр и из 3 цифр. Далее нужно прочитать этот двунаправленный список с конца и создать новый однонаправленный список, в котором будут содержаться только семизначные номера

Comment: Скорее всего вылетает по эксепшену. Оберните код в try...except и выведите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: @zed поясните подробнее, пожалуйста, про эксепшен и про try except

Comment: [Delphi: Except](https://delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/Except.php.html)

Comment: @zed номер ошибки $C0000005

Comment: У вас происходит обращение к неинициализированной памяти.  Следите, все ли линки вы поддерживаете в надлежащем состоянии